# Getting Blank Page on Shopping Cart And Checkout When Logged in Magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento-1.9

We have Magento 1.9.3.6, customer logs are on to enable comparison feature. If compilation is on and customer is logging in and clicking to shopping cart it goes to blank page. Nothing in system.log neither in php_errorlog. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Trying including the below 2 lines of code in index.php and see if you find any errors.

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: that doesn't show anything. It's a white screen, nothing is there. Once I turned off compilation it started working, but website is slower now.